# How to remove trailing slash from URLs?

Tags: url, htaccess

I would like to remove duplicate URLs by removing the trailing slash from URLs. If someone enters a URL like `http://example.com/something/` it should 301 redirect to `http://example.com/something`.

Obviously the query string must be preserved when present.

Here is my `.htaccess` file at the moment (for localhost):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /~macuser/example.com/
# RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /~macuser/example.com/index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Also, please feel free to comment if the above can be improved in any way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your .htacces you can use

```
# remove trailing slash
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(\?.*)?$ $1$2 [R=301,L]
```

To improve the urls on your page you can use my little plugin called 'remove_trailing_slash'. It is not yet aproved by devot-ee, but i can send you the plugin right away.

The usage is simple:

`{exp:remove_trailing_slash url="www.google.nl/"}` 
or
`{exp:remove_trailing_slash}www.google.nl/{/remove_trailing_slash}`

http://reinos.nl/add-ons/remove-trailing-slash/

Please pm me your email so i can send it to you.

Comment: Awesome thanks that worked a charm!! I do not think that I need to process the URLs in my output HTML because those do not include trailing slashes (or at least none that I am aware of).

Answer (score 0):

I used the following in my htaccess to redirect the urls with a trailing slash:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^\.localhost$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```